# C# Inheritance access confusion

Tags: c#-4.0

```
    public class ABC
    {
    }

    public class DEF : ABC
    {
    }

    public class Class1
    {
        ABC abc = new DEF(); //No error
        DEF def = new ABC(); //Compile time error
    }
```

Can anyone explain to me this scenario.
and under what circumstances we might use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called as Ploymorphism .
As explained in MSDN

> At run time, objects of a derived class may be treated as objects of a
>   base class in places such as method parameters and collections or
>   arrays. When this occurs, the object's declared type is no longer
>   identical to its run-time type.
>
> Base classes may define and implement virtual methods, and derived
>   classes can override them, which means they provide their own
>   definition and implementation. At run-time, when client code calls the
>   method, the CLR looks up the run-time type of the object, and invokes
>   that override of the virtual method. Thus in your source code you can
>   call a method on a base class, and cause a derived class's version of
>   the method to be executed.

The answer of for this question is best explained here [MSDN Polymorphism](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173152.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Its because as per the OOD rule you can assign child to parent but you cannot assign parent to child.

```
   //this possible as you re assigning child to parent 
   ABC abc = new DEF(); //No error
  //this is illegal as you are trying to assign child to parent directly
  DEF def = new ABC(); //Compile time error
```

Reconsider your design again or if you want to convert parent object to child than you need method for that conversion directly its not possible to do it as per OOD rules.

---

Consider real time example relation of Customer and RetailCustomer or Corporatecustomer of bank. Where you can easily say RetailCustomer or CorporateCustomer is Customer, but you cannot say Customer is RetailCustomer or CorporateCustomer because customer can be of any type.

Same goes for relation between Parent Shape Class and Child Rectangle,Circle etc. class.

Comment: Thanks. I just asked it here because someone in the interview asked me this question and I got confused...like child in a crowd confused!

Comment: @MayurMohite - apart from accepted answer you can also put some real world senario as I have given in updated answer...

Answer (score 1):

Let's say `ABC` is `Person`, while `DEF` is `Student` (which is a subclass of `Person`). You can always treat a `Student` as a `Person`, so the assignment to `abc` (of type `Person`) of a `Student` is correct, but you cannot treat a generic `Person` as `Student`, so the assignment to `def` is wrong (for instance, you cannot get the student number of a person which is not a student)

Comment: yeah...simple logic, Thank you!